# slide animation multiple divs toggle

Tags: animation, html, toggle, slide

I have 3 divs at the bottom of the page each with a link.

what i am trying to do

when i click a link the div will slide up 400px, #maincontent will fade out and if any of the other 2 are open then they will slide down so only 1 is fully visible at a time and if none are open the #maincontent will fade back in.

I can get them to animate up and down on click event but i cant get the others to go back to there original position.

any help would be much appreciated.

html

```
    <div class="poolbox1"><a class="poolview1" href="#"></a>content</div>
    <div class="poolbox2"><a class="poolview2" href="#"></a>content</div>
    <div class="poolbox3"><a class="poolview3" href="#"></a>content</div>
```

css

```
.poolview1{ float:right; margin-top:-25px; display:block; width:31px; height:31px; background-image:url(images/accept.png); background-repeat:no-repeat}
.poolbox2{width:300px; float:left; height:400px; background-color:#666666; margin-top:-20px;opacity: 0.9; filter: alpha(opacity=90);}
```

jquery

```
$(".poolview1").click(function(){
     $(".poolbox1").animate({
          marginTop: "-=400px",          
          height: "+=400px"
    }, 1000);
     $(".poolview1").fadeOut(1000);
     $("#maincontent").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".poolview2").click(function(){
     $(".poolbox2").animate({
          marginTop: "-=400px",          
          height: "+=400px"
    }, 1000);
     $(".poolview2").fadeOut(1000);
     $("#maincontent").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".poolview3").click(function(){
     $(".poolbox3").animate({
          marginTop: "-=400px",          
          height: "+=400px"
    }, 1000);
     $(".poolview3").fadeOut(1000);
     $("#maincontent").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/LcCkR/2/)**

html

```
<div id="poolbox1" class="poolbox"><a id="poolview1" class="poolview" href="#">poolview1</a>content</div>
<div id="poolbox2" class="poolbox"><a id="poolview2" class="poolview" href="#">poolview2</a>content</div>
<div id="poolbox3" class="poolbox"><a id="poolview3" class="poolview" href="#">poolview3</a>content</div>​
```

css

```
.poolview{float:right; display:block; width:31px; height:31px; }
.poolbox{width:150px; float:left; height:400px; background-color:#666666;opacity: 0.9; filter: alpha(opacity=90);}
```

jquery

```
$(".poolview").click(function(){
     $(".poolbox").animate({
          marginTop: "400px",          
          height: "0px"
     }, 1000);
     $(this).parent().animate({
          marginTop: "0px",          
          height: "400px"
     }, 1000);
     $(".poolview").fadeIn(1000);
     $(this).fadeOut(1000);
     $("#maincontent").fadeOut(1000);
});​
```

Comment: that is so close to what i am trying to do. the 3 boxes only show the top as the rest is below the footer, when i click they need to stay where they are and just the clicked one to slide all the way up, if you are unsure just let me know and ill try to explain better lol

Comment: thank you, made a few simple changes and all seems to be doing what it should lol.

Comment: updated demo link and click the tick mark if my ans was useful to you :)